Estimates on Covering Number for Convex Polytopes Partitioning a Convex Set
Consider a convex set $K\in\mathbb{R}^3$ and a collection of convex 3-polytopes $C^i\subseteq K$ of equal volume $\frac{1}{N}$ for $i\in(1,\ldots,N)$ that partition $K$ (a Voronoi or Laguerre diagram if you like). Do there exist any estimates on the covering number of the convex sets $C^i$ by balls of volume $\frac{1}{N}$ as $N\to\infty$ ?
Any suggestions or recommendations for books or papers would be much appreciated.
P.S. This will most definitely depend on the shape of the convex polytopes but for example is having a partition given by cuboids with $\mathrm{diam}(K)$ the worst possible partition in the sense that it maximises the covering number ?
